# Azure Cloud Role included storage = extra costs?

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I'm currently working out the cost-analysis for my upcoming Azure project. I am tempted to use a Azure Cloud Role, because it has a certain amount of storage included in the offer. However, I have the feeling that it is too good to be true.

Therefore, I was wondering. Do you have to pay transaction-costs/ storage costs on this "included" storage? I can't find any information about this on the Azure website, and I want to be as accurate as possible (even if the cost of transactions is almost nothing).

EDIT:
To clarify, I specifically want to know about the transaction costs on the storage. Do you have to pay a small cost per transaction on the storage (like with Blob/Table storage), or is this included in the offer as well?

EDIT 2:
I am talking about the storage included with the Cloud Services (web/worker) and not a separate Table/blob storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you clarify which offer you're referring to?

With Cloud Services (web/worker roles), each VM instance has some local storage associated with it, which is free of charge and, because it's a local disk, there are no transactions or related fees associated with this storage. As Rik pointed out in his answer, that data is not durable: it's on a single disk and will be gone forever if, say, the disk crashes.

If you're storing data in Blobs, Tables, or Queues (Windows Azure Storage), then you pay per GB ($0.095 cents per GB per month for geo-redundant storage, or $0.07 per GB per month for locally-redundant storage), and a penny per 100,000 transactions. And as long as your storage account is in the same data center as your Cloud Service, there's no data egress fees.

Now we come back to the question of which offer you're referring to. The free 90-day trial, for instance, comes with 70GB of Windows Azure Storage, and 50M transactions monthly included. MSDN subscriptions come with included storage and transactions as well. If you're just working with a pay-as-you-go subscription, you'll pay for storage plus transactions.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was indeed talking about the Cloud Services (worker/web) and the local storage included in those. My term "offer" may have been misplace, because i actually meant the "offer" at pay-as-you-go.

I am confused however, since, with a normal Virtual Machine, you do have to pay for storage transactions on the disk (because the "local disk on those VM's is in fact a Blob Storage-disk, so you pay for the transactions)

Comment: Yes, Virtual Machines are backed by a vhd in a page blob, so you're paying transactions. This goes for attached disks as well. With Cloud Services (web/worker), the OS disk is stateless (basically spun up for you, and if need be, recreated, without you ever worrying about it), and stored on local disk since it doesn't matter if it ever crashes; a new one is simply rebuilt based on the baseline image. Bottom line: Even if you drive 50 million transactions monthly to a virtual machine disk, that's... $5.00.

Answer (score 0):

The storage is included, but not guaranteed to be persistent. Your role could be shut down and started on a different physical location, which has no impact on the availability of your role, but you'll lose your whatever you have in storage, I.E. the included storage is very much temporary.

As for transaction costs, you only pay for outgoing data, not incoming data or data within Azure (one role to another).

You pay per GB, and $0,01 per 100.000 transactions

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was actually asking for the transactions on the data itself. For example, if you are using Table/blob-storage, you need to pay a little for every transaction, regardsless of the fact if the transaction started from within the center, or outside.

Comment: You pay per GB, and $0,01 per 100.000 transactions